# Jquery AJAX call not finding Rails route

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm working on a project where I need to be able to mark certain objects for review or deletion. I'm using checkboxes, then using `JavaScript` to harvest the data from the checkboxes. I'm trying to use `AJAX` to send that data back to the `Rails Controller` but I keep getting a 404 error, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

This is the `AJAX` call (review_list and purge_list are both defined, I've checked):

```
function callHandleSelected() {
...
  $.post('itemresults/handle_selected', { review: review_list, purge: purge_list },
      function(data) {
          alert(data);
      });
}
```

And this is the route I wrote to match it:

```
post 'itemresults/handle_selected', to: 'processed_item#handle_selected'
```

I've tried adding `as: :ajax` into the route to see if that makes a difference without any luck.

The HTML element that calls the ajax function looks like so:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-normal" onclick="callHandleSelected()">Mark Selected as Reviewed and/or for Purge</button>
```

There is also a matching `handle_selected` method in my Ruby Controller. Every time I try to use the `AJAX` method I get the following error:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/itemresults/handle_selected 404 (Not Found) jquery.js?body=1:9667
  jQuery.ajaxTransport.send jquery.js?body=1:9667
  jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js?body=1:9212
  jQuery.each.jQuery.(anonymous function) jquery.js?body=1:9358
  callHandleSelected processed_item.js?body=1:37
  onclick
```

In case you need it, here is the `controller` method:

```
def handle_selected
  review_list = params[:review]
  purge_list = params[:purge]
  review_list.each do |item|
    item.split("_")
    proc_item = ProcessedItem.find(item[1])
    proc_item.reviewed = true;
    proc_item.save!
  end
  purge_list.each do |item|
    item.split("_")
    proc_item = ProcessedItem.find(item[1])
    proc_item.purge = true;
    proc_item.save!
  end
  redirect_to processed_items_path()
  #add alert
end
```

Comment: What is in handle_selected in your controller?

Comment: Edited my post to include that method.

Comment: Your controller action doesn't respond to a javascript request, it should render something in context of `json` too. Also, make sure that this is the correct path for POST request. You specified that in `config/routes.rb` right?

Comment: Yep, ajax call can't do a redirect_to

Comment: `ProcessedItem.find(item[1])` will throw a 404 if it doesn't find a `ProcessedItem`

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is just that you need a leading slash on your request url:

```
$.post('itemresults/handle_selected' ...
```

should be

```
$.post('/itemresults/handle_selected'
```

Without the leading slash, it will add the url onto the end of the current page url.

EDIT:  you should put a leading slash on the path in your routes.rb file as well.  I think that rails "forgives" you for not doing this but i'm not sure: either way you should do it properly, ie with the leading slash.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of the comments on my initial post answered the question. I took out the `redirect_to` line and replaced it with this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js {render inline: "location.reload();" }
end
```

I was getting the 404 error because I was trying to load objects incorrectly as Baloo pointed out. The new (relevant) code looks like this:

```
review_list.each do |item|
  id = item.split("_")[1]
  proc_item = ProcessedItem.find(id)
```

Thanks all!

Comment: Does anyone know how to keep that `respond_to` block from popping up a dialog box? It opens up a box that says, `"location.reload();"` and you have to click OK before the page actually refreshes.